# List collections based on document IDs

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire2

I am trying to list all the documents whose IDs are given in an array.

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    function checkUserId(orgId) {
      return ('user_id' in resource.data.keys() && request.auth.uid==resource.data.user_id)
        || orgId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.auth.uid)).data.organisationIds;
    }

    function checkAdminToken() {
      return 'lectusAdmin' in request.auth.token.keys() && request.auth.token.lectusAdmin
    }

    match /organisation/{document=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if isSignedIn() && (checkUserId(document) || checkAdminToken()); // This is line 20
      allow create: if isSignedIn();
    }

  }

}
```

And my Angular 10 code is:

```
this.organisationCollection = this._angularFirestore.collection<Organisation>('organisation');
this.organisations = this.organisationCollection.valueChanges({idField: 'id'});
```

I tried to add a `where` in the collection - `.where('id', 'in', org.organisationIds)`, where `id` is the document ID (I think so) that checks in the array of `org.organisationIds`. Again I am not sure if I need this because the rules should be able to figure that out.

I get an error as - `false for 'list' @ L20` that's - `allow read, update, delete: if isSignedIn() && (checkUserId(document) || checkAdminToken());`

This works fine when I try to get a document using `orginisation/<document ID>` but I am not able to list them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is the fact that [Firestore security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  Please read that documentation carefully.  Rules will **not** check the contents of each document in the entire set of query results - that does not scale in the way that Firestore requires.  Firestore scales up to billions or more documents per collection.  Reading and checking every document is out of the question.

Your query is declaring that it wants **all** of the documents in the "organisation" collection.  Since the rules cannot ensure that every single document is readable using the checks you have now (that must check the contents of each document, and even additional documents), they simply fail the entire query.

The only way to get your query to work is if it matches the rules requirements.  For example, if your rules require that the user's ID must equal the field "user_id" in the document, then you need to add the user's UID as a filter on that field in the query.  But you will still not be able to `get()` other documents in the rule based on fields in the resource document (as it's still not going to read each document to check it).

Comment: OK. I don't want it to check the contents of each document, `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.auth.uid)).data.organisationIds` returns an array. All I want to check is if the requested IDs are available in this or not. Or is that what is happening and that's not possible?

Comment: Your rules are using the contents of a specific document any time you see `resource`.  If you use that for a query that could return multiple documents, it will just fail.

Comment: Ah got it. any recommendation on this, because if I don't check for that, `checkUserId()` fails at first condition because the resource might not have `user_id` and this could be a security issue

Comment: My recommendation was to make the query match the rules by adding a filter.

Comment: something like `where('id', 'in', org.organisationIds)`? But the document doesn't have an `id` field, and I don't know how to get the document ID in its collection while using `where` query

Comment: I tried this `where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', org.organisationIds)` and it worked, I think there is still a security issue